# IIS-Express SSL settings

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I use Visual studio 2019. When I start debugging my web app I get Error:

> HTTP Error 403.4 – Forbidden The page you are trying to access is
>   secured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

I have already set in project properties SSL enabled to false. I also deleted applicationhost.config in .vs\config. I also deleted applicationhost.config in location C:\Users...\Documents\IISExpress\config.

But all with no success. I am still geting the same error.
What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to end up with a website that does not use https, or is this just for debugging purposes?

Comment: I would not use https in dev environment. I would use SSL in test and prod.

Comment: Did you check that the "Project Url" in the "Servers" section on the "Web" tab in the project properties is not set to use https?

Comment: VS2019 changed the config file path once again (still in .vs folder).

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could also check the url you have used is http not https.

Comment: I use http in url and I do not override it in servers section on web tab of project properties, but steel same result.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select project in Solution Explorer
2. F4 to get to properties
3. Change SSL enable to False